# RSA encryption/decryption in c

Tags: c, public-key-encryption

i am trying to implement rsa algorithm using c program. it works well in most cases.But in some cases it does not encrypt and again decrypt back to same stage.for example: "--" after encryption and decryption changes to "ƒƒ"
here is the code for encryption and decryption. help would be appreciated. thanks in advance

```
void encrypt(uChar state[16])
{
    long int pt,ct,key=e[0],k;
    i=0;
    while(i<=16)
    {
        pt=state[i];
        pt=pt-96;
        k=1;
        for (j=0;j<key;j++)
        {
            k=k*pt;
            k=k%n;
        }
    ct=k+96;
    state[i]=ct;
    i++;
    }
}

void decrypt(uChar state[16])
{
    long int pt,ct,key=d[0],k;
    i=0;
    while(i<=16)
    {
        ct=state[i]-96;
        k=1;
        for (j=0;j<key;j++)
        {
            k=k*ct;
            k=k%n;
        }
        pt=k+96;
        state[i]=pt;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the change still the problem persists.

Comment: What are `n` and `j` and `d` and `e`? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried.

Comment: What is `pt=pt-96;`? Is it supposed to be `pt - 'a'`? If so it is off by 1, and your message must be all lower case, I guess, but you haven't shown any sample input and output.

Comment: n is the variable which holds the value of p*q in rsa. as all know j is the iterator. e is the public key of receiver and d is the private key of the receiver

Comment: here uChar represents unsigned char in order to keep the values within the range i have subtracted it with 96

Comment: actually now i found that there is no problem in the encryption and decryption function .but still there are errors in the file. i am getting input from a file and processing them in batches of 16

Comment: http://jmp.sh/v/dcGNoe3a3JbiVCeihBJB this the link for file

Answer (score 2):

You are indexing outside the bounds of the array with

```
while(i<=16)
```

You can index `state[16]` only up to `15` so (in both functions) it should be

```
while(i < 16)
```